# Loading text file (row col array format with \t and \n delimiters) of complex numbers (form "%.4le + %.4lei) into matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a text file in array form of complex numbers in the form for example 5+6i or 5+-6i etc.  They are in row, column arrangement in text file.  I have been using q = load('filename').  However, this seems to drop the imaginary part of the number.  There must be a simple way to load an array of complex numbers?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please [edit] the question with at least a sample of your file (don't post thousands of rows, just a few representative ones will do) If you've already written some code, do show that see [mre]. That said, this seems like a job for [`strsplit()`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html). Load your file row-by-row, then `strsplit(row, '+')` and stitch the two parts back together as numerals (possibly after removing the `i`).

Comment: Does the solution in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46475306/matlab-read-complex-numbers-from-text-file?rq=2 work?

Comment: Ultimatly, if you have a very niche format, you may need to loop row by row and process it yourself with fread